# Loading ngMock only in testing context when using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-ngmock, ngmocke2e

I'm switching all of our protractor E2E tests of an angular app to `ngMock`, so that we can mock our resources/http calls. However, I can't find a recommended method for loading `ngMock` in that scenario.

I don't want to include the script itself in my live app of course, but I'm not seeing a clear method through protractor for injecting an extra `script` element, or dynamically loading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do is to use [grunt-targethtml](https://github.com/changer/grunt-targethtml) or [gupl-targethtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-targethtml) so in your `index.html` you can add conditions of when to add an script or not:

```
    <!--(if target  mock || e2e)><!-->
    <script src="dev-mocks/mock-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="dev-mocks/modules/authentication-service-mock.js"></script>
    <!--<!(endif)-->
```

First configure your grunt task to execute the `targethtml` task with the `target` `e2e`/`mock`

```
 grunt.registerTask(
    'e2e',
    'Automated tests',
    function(target) {
      var tasks = [
          'clean:server',
          'targethtml:e2e',
          'concurrent:server',
          'autoprefixer',
          'connect:e2e'
        ];
        return grunt.task.run(tasks);
    });
```

[Here](https://github.com/thematho/cucumber-protractor-template) is a working template with all the tasks, packages and logic necessary to implement [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) + [CucumberJS](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/) + [sugar-step](https://github.com/ldegen/sugar-step) (for easy sync-async steps executions), and also inject mock modules dinamically using the @Around method of CucumberJS

Comment: I really don't want ngMock anywhere in my actual application templates, even if it's just going to be removed in a gulp task, but part of the issue is that everything in the app is loaded with `requirejs`.

Comment: The cleaner way is yo use targethtml, Otherwise you will have to do what targethtml does by hand, has you said, using requiredjs with a particular gulp task and load the mock modules into your angular application manually